# How to open custom wikidata RDF dumps

Tags: dump, wikidata

I have created a custom wikidata dump from https://wdumps.toolforge.org/ . Can anyone please tell me how to open and read that dump file ? File comes in .nt format

You can find recent dump files here: https://wdumps.toolforge.org/dumps

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you want to read it. With visual studio code you can just open the file and see inside it. Other text editors should also work I think. Or do you want to have a more specific app for it?

Also its handy to mention if you'r on windows or not.

update:

You first need to unzip it, you can do this with winzip on a command line or a library in any language that does this.

https://support.winzip.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011594767-How-to-extract-gzip-and-tar-files-on-the-command-line

then you will get a file with lines like this:

```
<http://wikiba.se/ontology#Property> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> .
```

from there you can parse it with regex to get the pages out of it, dunno what you want? property, type or class?

Comment: I just want to get title of pages nothing else. Can you please guide how to export only pages title in a file not anything from inside that page. I am on windows.